How to use AWS EventBridge to pass a table name to the lambda and report via email if the lambda errors
I can set up AWS EventBridge, managed entirely through Terraform, to schedule the recurrent execution of a Lambda function every hour. During each execution, EventBridge will send a specific table name as a parameter to the Lambda. Within the Lambda function, there's a logic to extract data from a Splunk table, with the target table defined in a 'query' variable. Additionally, I'd like to implement error handling: if the Lambda encounters an error, EventBridge will not trigger it again but instead send an email notification informing of the error.
So far, I've only managed to trigger the lambda via EventBridge; as for the rest, I'm not even sure if it's still possible
